# 'script' session logging makes me exit twice

Tags: bash, ssh, bashrc, exit

I'm using a solution described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25725/37050) to log my shell sessions, by adding this to the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
test "$(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | awk '{print $1}')" == 'script' || (script -f /var/log/shellog/$USER-$(date -u +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S).${HOSTNAME:-$(hostname)}.$$.log)
```

This works fine, however, when I exit the shell, I have to exit twice: once from the script, and once from the shell:

```
Last login: Wed Aug  6 12:43:29 2014 from *****
Script started, file is /var/log/shellog/camilstaps-2014.08.06-10:43:40.cs.localdomain.16048.log
camilstaps@cs:/$ exit
exit
Script done, file is /var/log/shellog/camilstaps-2014.08.06-10:43:40.cs.localdomain.16048.log
camilstaps@cs:/$ exit
exit
```

I found [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Shell/Q_24039472.html), and tried modifying the line in `/etc/bash.bashrc` accordingly, but this doesn't change anything:

```
test "$(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | awk '{print $1}')" == 'script' || (script -f /var/log/shellog/$USER-$(date -u +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S).${HOSTNAME:-$(hostname)}.$$.log && exit)
```

I suppose it's because I have to `test` that I'm not in `script` already (without the `test` it keeps making new `script`s). But how can I make that I don't have to exit twice?

Comment: What does `ps -ocommand= -p $PPID` return ?

Comment: @val0x00ff `script -f /var/log/shellog/camilstaps-2014.08.06-11:12:11.cs.localdomain.16164.log`

Comment: so that will always match. With awk you are printing the first field which is `script`. Everything after `||` will never get executed.

Comment: @val0x00ff well, it is executed when I start the session, of course. I'm not sure if I understand what you're getting at.

Comment: Camil, what does this do:  `[[ "$(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | awk '{print $1}')" = script ]] || { script -f /var/log/shellog/$USER-$(date -u +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S).${HOSTNAME:-$(hostname)}.$$.log && exit ;}`  I mean, try to put the code within `[[ .. ]]` keyword and group the command after `||`

Comment: @val0x00ff that works! Thank you very much. I don't understand why exactly, but I'll try to figure it out. Could you add it as an answer?

Comment: Camil, the command you had within `()`  will run in a subshell. This means another process is created. Read more about it here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell

Comment: @val0x00ff I see, thank you very much, also for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested.  The following should work

```
[[ $(ps -ocommand= -p $PPID | awk '{print $1}') = script ]] || { script -f /var/log/shellog/$USER-$(date -u +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S).${HOSTNAME:-$(hostname)}.$$.log && exit ;}
```