# Source ~/.bashrc when using the shell recorder `script`

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, terminal

I am using the first answer from

[How to automatically record all your terminal sessions with script utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25639/how-to-automatically-record-all-your-terminal-sessions-with-script-utility)

to record my terminal sessions, however, I can not figure out how to get my bashrc to be sourced and record the sessions automatically....

Any ideas are greatly appreciated =]

Comment: Turns out, its /etc/bashrc thats not sourced =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bashrc` is sourced by default.

```
-bash-4.1$ echo 'echo I was read' >> ~/.bashrc
-bash-4.1$ script asdf
Script started, file is asdf
I was read
bash-4.1$ exit
Script done, file is asdf
```

Comment: hrmm, I guess its /etc/bashrc thats not sourced... is that because of the .bash_profile?